# Get chained property names from MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a form builder for MVC and I want to simulate Razor's treatment of chained properties in the following way:

```
builder.TextBoxFor(x => x.User.Email);
```

Which would produce the following in the same manner as Razor:

```
<input id="User_Email" name="User.Email" type="textbox" />
```

The following code works for a single level of chaining (e.g. `x.Email` produces `Email`), but I'm trying to detect when there is a parent before the final property and then use recursion to go back up the chain (or at least go one step up).

```
private static string GetFieldName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

How can I adapt this so that `x.User.Email` produces `User.Email` and not just `Email` as it does currently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a little recursion:

```
private static string GetPropertyPath<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var propertyPath = new Stack<string>();
    var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

    do
    {
        propertyPath.Push(body.Member.Name);

        // this will evaluate to null when we will reach ParameterExpression (x in "x => x.Foo.Bar....")
        body = body.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }
    while (body != null);

    return string.Join(".", propertyPath);
}
```